# How to handle the collision between two arraylist objects?

Tags: java, arraylist, collision

I have a problem with my code here. I want to make a game with thow ball on each side of screen, on ball being controlled by the user and the other one by the computer. Both ball shoot to each other, and if the bullets intersects one with another, i need to make something happen. I managed to do some thing here, and I have two class, one for the player bullets, and the other one for the enemies bullets, and the bullets are created trough arraylists. All works fin until now, but if I try ti make them collision with each other,it doesnt work at all. I've tried a lot of things but none of it worked, and I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

That is the Player Projectile class:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Projectiles {

private int x, y, speedX;
private boolean visible;
private int width = 10;
private int height = 10;

private Rectangle r;

public Projectiles(){

}

public Projectiles(int startX, int startY) {

    x = startX;
    y = startY;
    speedX = 1;
    visible = true;

    r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);

}

public void update(){

    x += speedX;

    r.setBounds(x, y, width, height);

    if (x > 800){
        visible = false;
        r = null;
    }

    if (x < 800){
        checkCollision();
    }

}

private void checkCollision() {



}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public int getSpeedX() {
    return speedX;
}

public boolean isVisible() {
    return visible;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public void setSpeedX(int speedX) {
    this.speedX = speedX;
}

public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    this.visible = visible;
}

public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setWidth(int width) {
    this.width = width;
}

public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public Rectangle getR() {
    return r;
}

public void setR(Rectangle r) {
    this.r = r;
}

}
```

And this one is the Enemy_Projectile class:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Enemy_Projectiles {

private int x, y, speedX;
private boolean visible;
private int width = 30;
private int height = 20;

public static Rectangle r;

Projectiles p1;

public Enemy_Projectiles(int startX, int startY) {

    x = startX;
    y = startY;
    speedX = 1;
    visible = true;

    r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);

}

public void update() {

    x -= speedX;

    r.setBounds(x, y, width, height);

    if (x < 0) {
        visible = false;
        r = null;
    }

    if (x > 0){
        checkCollision();
    }

}

private void checkCollision() {

    if(r.intersects(p1.getR())){
        visible = false;
        System.out.println("Coliziune!!");
    }

}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public int getSpeedX() {
    return speedX;
}

public boolean isVisible() {
    return visible;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public void setSpeedX(int speedX) {
    this.speedX = speedX;
}

public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    this.visible = visible;
}

public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setWidth(int width) {
    this.width = width;
}

public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
}

}
```

Comment: "_I've tried a lot of things but none of it worked_" What did you try in terms of collisions and what didn't work about it? We don't need to sort through all of your code for helping with just this. Consider making an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could you post what you have tried for the `intersects(...)` method?

Comment: Yes, I see you calling it but I don't see it defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Do not check intersection after the frame has been drawn. Let's say you have a slow computer and your bullets intersect, but they have moved out of intersection in one frame.

You need to apply high school physics/geometry. Calculate where the bullet will be well before you render it. Then, calculate where the ball will be, and construct a line segment for each from where they are now, to where they will be on the next frame. Check if these segments intersect. Then you will have a fool-proof method of checking for intersection.

This method is similar to how physics and intersections between objects are handled inside of a game engine like Unity.